# node-soap appending "Request" to wsdl methods

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap, wsdl, node-soap

so I'm trying to execute the following

```
soapClient.getDeptUser({
        UserName : "temp",
        UserPassword : "temp"
     },
        userNumber : "xxxxxx"
    }}, (err,result) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(soapClient.lastRequest);
        }else{
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
```

But I keep getting the error from the web service as: Cannot identify any WSDL operation from request.

My last request looks like this:

```
<soap:Body Id="_0">
  <getDeptUserRequest>
    <User>
      <UserName>temp</UserName>
      <UserPassword>temp</UserPassword
    </User>
      <userNumber>xxxxx</userNumber>
  </getDeptUserRequest>
</soap:Body>
```

I think the problem is because there is no method called getDeptUserRequest but I'm trying to call getDeptUser not sure how to prevent the word Request from being appended onto the method name.

WSDL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://webservices.cxfdept.fbem"    
    xmlns:tns1="http://pojo.webservices.cxf.fbem"
    xmlns:schema="http://methods.webservices.cxf.fbem" 
    xmlns:tns="http://webservices.cxfdept.fbem"
      xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
      xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
      xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
      xmlns:soapenc11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
      xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <!-- ****************************************************** -->
    <!-- ***  import complex types definitions for this XSD ***-->
    <!-- ****************************************************** -->
    <wsdl:import namespace="http://methods.webservices.cxf.fbem" location="WsFBEMDept_methods_01.xsd"></wsdl:import>
    <!-- *************************************************** -->
    <!-- *******    Set messages ****************************-->
    <!-- *************************************************** -->
    <!-- getDeptUserRequest -->
    <wsdl:message name="getDeptUserRequest">
      <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="schema:getDeptUser"/>
    </wsdl:message>  
    <wsdl:message name="getDeptUserResponse">
      <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="schema:getDeptUserResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <!-- ****************************************************** -->
    <!-- *******   Set portTypes                            *** -->
    <!-- ****************************************************** -->
    <wsdl:portType name="WsFBEMDeptServiceV1001PortType">
      <wsdl:operation name="getDeptUser">
        <wsdl:input name="getDeptUserRequest" message="tns:getDeptUserRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output name="getDeptUserResponse" message="tns:getDeptUserResponse"/>
      </wsdl:operation>
    <!-- ****************************************************** -->
    <!-- ****   Set Bindings                                *** -->
    <!-- ****************************************************** -->
      <wsdl:binding name="WsFBEMDeptServiceV1001HttpBinding" type="tns:WsFBEMDeptServiceV1001PortType">
      <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <!-- getDeptUser -->
        <wsdl:operation name="getDeptUser">
        <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
          <wsdl:input name="getDeptUserRequest">
          <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output name="getDeptUserResponse">
          <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation> 
    <!-- ****************************************************** -->
    <!-- ***     Set Service                                *** -->
    <!-- ****************************************************** -->
      <wsdl:service name="WsFBEMDeptServiceV1001">
        <wsdl:port name="WsFBEMDeptServiceV1001HttpPort" binding="tns:WsFBEMDeptServiceV1001HttpBinding">
          <wsdlsoap:address location="http://127.0.0.1:8080/fbem_cxfDept/services/WsFBEMDeptServiceV1001"/>
      </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
  </wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Can you show WSDL itself?

Comment: Sorry for the long wait had to make sure I could publish the wsdl file as this is an internal soap service.  I can't post the whole wsdl but I can post parts of it.

Comment: So I found out that it's differently pulling the Request word from part of the wsdl, I'm not that familiar with soap so not sure how to fix it.

Comment: @raina77ow
Ok so I found in client.js

    `assert.ok(!style || style === 'document', 'invalid message definition for rpc style binding');
    // pass `input.$lookupType` if `input.$type` could not be found
    message = self.wsdl.objectToDocumentXML(input.$name, args, input.targetNSAlias, input.targetNamespace, (input.$type || input.$lookupType));
  }`
style = type 'document' 
If I changed input.$name to the var 'name' which is set to method.$name which is the correct name for the soap method.  I'm not sure if this is a bug or just a way I found to get the results I needed.